# Как добавить переместить значение переменной из одного метода в другой? Пытаюсь написать приложение для построения графика функции

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, matplotlib

У меня возникла сложность с тем, чтобы взять значение переменной `textboxValue` из метода `on_click` и передать в метод `initUI`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenu, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, QMessageBox, QWidget, \
    QPushButton, QLineEdit
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Тест'
        self.left = 60
        self.top = 60
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox.move(500, 500)
        self.textbox.resize(280, 40)
        self.button = QPushButton('Показать', self)
        self.button.move(400, 400)
        m = PlotCanvas(self, width=5, height=4)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        m.plot("x**2") # в скобках должна быть переменная

        self.show()
    def on_click(self):
        self.textboxValue = self.textbox.text()
        print(self.textboxValue)

class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)


    def plot(self, m):
        x = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)

        y = eval(m)
        #y = x**2
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(x, y)

        self.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

https://github.com/PyScientist/Plot_function/blob/master/Plot_function.py
вопрос решен, пользуйтесь кому нужно)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenu, QVBoxLayout, \
    QSizePolicy, QMessageBox, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def plot(self, m):
        x = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
        y = eval(m)
        #y = x**2
#?        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
#        ax.plot(x, y)
        self.axes.clear()                                                 # +++
        self.axes.plot(x, y)                                              # +++
        self.draw()
        

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Тест'
        self.left = 60
        self.top = 60
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
#        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox.move(500, 500)
        self.textbox.resize(280, 40)
        self.button = QPushButton('Показать', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.button.move(400, 400)
        
        self.m = PlotCanvas(self, width=5, height=4)                      # +++ self
#        m.plot("x**2")                              # в скобках должна быть переменная
#        self.m.plot(f"x**{self.textboxValue}")

    def on_click(self):
        textboxValue = self.textbox.text()
        print(textboxValue)
        self.m.plot(f"x**{textboxValue}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.resize(800, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Alina что с моим ответом не так?

Answer (score 0):

> У меня возникла сложность с тем, чтобы переместить переменную textboxValue метода on_click в метод initUI.

```
class App():
    textboxValue: str
    def __init__(self):
        self.on_click()     
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        print(self.textboxValue)

    def on_click(self):
        self.textboxValue = 'some text...'

a = App()
```